# What does the GRG in Excel Solver's GRG Non Linear Optimization stand for?

Tags: excel, solver, acronym

Just curious, I can't seem to find any information about this effective optimization method.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with professional software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solver uses Generalized Reduction Gradient Algorithm

> Microsoft Excel Solver uses the Generalized Reduced Gradient (GRG2)
>   Algorithm for optimizing nonlinear problems. This algorithm was
>   developed by Leon Lasdon, of the University of Texas at Austin, and
>   Allan Waren, of Cleveland State University.

From:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/82890